# Query to read records updated/Created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I migrate date from one database to another and I need to move the new or updated data. However, some tables do not have any date fields to know when it was created or updated.
Is there a way to get the records that were modified within a period of time in a table in SQL Server without having a field(created or updated date) that traces that?

I tried something like this

```
select object_id
from sys.objects
where name = 'tablename';

select top 1 *
from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
where object_id = @object_id 
  and last_user_update is not null
order by last_user_update;
```

Comment: The standard "stats" queries won't give you that type of information that you're after.  SQL has some "built-in" change tracking that you can enable (meaning you don't need to add your own create/update fields) - but I'd suggest being very careful with it, as it can lead to significant database growth, if not kept in check.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: If the things are bad and you need to prove something the only thing you can do is to look at the backups. If you have regular tlog backups you can search for tools, queries to find when and by who event happens

Comment: Change tracking works quite well, but you need to be able to enable that. You can also check out "change data capture", or create triggers that do it manually. Finally in the worst case, you can try reading dB log and finding changes through that, but that's nuclear option. As usual, if you have a task and can't do things or don't have rights, work with your manager so someone gives you the rights

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it just by looking at the "plain" (i.e. the one without any change tracking or temporal stuff enabled)  table or its metadata.

In order to compare two databases you should use data comparison tools. There are plenty available online (search for "SQL Server data comparison"). Some free and some not so free. You may even be able to find some "home brew" scripts that compare table data between two different databases.